# How do I make a certain area of my uitextfield non editable?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I have inserted an image on top of a uitextfield.A small image like you see in most login screens.The problem is the user can type in that area.How do I make that area non editable.So that the user can only type after that image

Comment: Please attach the screenshot of your viewController.

Comment: reduce the textfield font size and set the textfield vertical content mode into center...

Comment: Asking a question means that you are explaining the question too.. As Rajan said please attach the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that method `- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` is what you are looking for [UITextField Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html):

> You should not call this method directly. If you want to provide a different editing rectangle for the text, you can override this method and return that rectangle. By default, this method returns a region in the text field that is not occupied by any overlay views.

Comment: This seems better than my previous answer +1